# FCM with notification & data payload is received without any data

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to receive push notification with data payload when app is in background/closed. But when parsing intent from onCreate/onNewIntent there are no extras data received.

Push request body is following:

```
{
 "data": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
  "type": "LOGIN",
        "intercomMessage": "test"
 },
"notification": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
  "type": "LOGIN",
        "intercomMessage": "test"
 },
 "to": "#push_token"
}
```

With data only FCM all works fine, but we need to support notification messages with data payload

Comment: Which URL you are using to send this request??

Comment: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Your URL is correct.. Are you checking for Extras data in launcher activity??

Comment: yes. In activity with <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> there are no extras (null), if I sent both data and notification. When sending data only, all works fine, but push is displayed without icon and text

Comment: In my case working perfect... Try matching these versions... and let me know.
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'`

Comment: Yes, already found, that obsolete firebase versions (16.0.8 and 18.0.0 respectively) causes that. So, it will be painfull to upgrade this legacy project:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202706/discussion-between-naitik-soni-and-wingear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found, what causes that: this conbination of flags in receiving activity.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

After receiving in another activity, all become works as expected

Answer (score 1):

- Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.
- You should use data payload to received data in onMessageReceived() and show notification

Comment: Yes, and with data-only notification all works as in documentation, problem is related to incorrect activity flags in manifest (see answer below).

Comment: You add FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or add "singleTop" in your activity AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following JSON

```
{
 "data": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
  "type": "LOGIN",
  "intercomMessage": "test"
 },
 "to": "#push_token",
 "priority": "high",
}
```

`notification` tag is not required

Comment: It's not possible now without changing server side: they sends pushes with both notification and data payload. With data only all works fine. I'm trying to fix this on the client

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the notification code within your MyFirebaseMessagingService class which u will create which will be extended from FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: Already created) Problem is related to receiving "data and notification" push message when app is backgrounded/closed

Comment: Have you initialized theFirebaseMessagingService class under your mainactivity otherwise background wont work!

Comment: Post your FirebaseMessagingService java class

Comment: Already found, what causes that: this conbination of flags in receiving activity. 
```
android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
```
After receiving in another activity, all become works as expected